# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable (in python)

Tags: python, selenium, typeerror

`this is my code:`
i don't know what is this error can someone help or explain me what is this?

```
import urllib, json
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
import time


def look_for_new_video():

    api_key = "AIzaSyAsYUSACp5yxSa_KF5W3EM2mW4gvtqe0zw"
    channel_id = "UCrMT-qEr5f7CN6osiiTS6Rg"
    base_video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
    base_search_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?'

    url = base_search_url + 'key={}&channelId={}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=1'.format(api_key, channel_id)
    inp = urllib.request(url)
    resp = json.load(inp)

    vidID= resp['items'][0]['id']['videoId']

    video_exists = False
    with open('videoid.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        if data['videoId'] != vidID:
            driver = webdriver.Firefox()
            driver.get(base_video_url + vidID)
            video_exists = True

    if video_exists:
        with open('videoid.json', 'w') as json_file:
            data = {'videoId' : vidID}
            json.dump(data, json_file)

try:
    while True:
        look_for_new_video()
        time.sleep(10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('stopping')
```

i don't know what is this error can someone help or explain me what is this?

so i don't know why but this error is bugging me all day cam someone help me out: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Can you add the whole error trace? This can often help you track down the issue

Comment: This is the number 1 problem with stackoverflow python questions. People won't post python traceback messages. Python showed you the line with the error. Why make it hard?

Comment: if i add this 'inp = urllib.request.Request(url)' it shows this error: 'AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'read''

Comment: @tdelaney Everyone makes that mistake. As long as you're learning from it :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking over this briefly it looks like the error is with your [request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request)

`inp = urllib.request(url)`

should be

`inp = urllib.request.Request(url)`

Comment: if i add this 'inp = urllib.request.Request(url)' it shows this error: 'AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'read''

Comment: Again, can you add the whole error? When you add the whole error there's a bit more information you can look at to help yourself determine the source of the issue. For example 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/.../py/stack_exchange.py", line 942, in <module>
    look_for_new_video()
  File "G:/.../py/stack_exchange.py", line 922, in look_for_new_video
    inp = urllib.request(url)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`
This error shows you the problem is happening at line 922, as shown in the traceback

Comment: this is the whole error: `File "C:\Users\lagis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'Request object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: @Lagis Looks like the `urllib.request.Request(url)` is not returning a JSON document. You might need to read up on the [interaction and types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)

Comment: yeh, but i don't  know what to do with this and how to fix it "[docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load] " cuz im new to programing

Comment: @Lagis No worries mate. Essentially what you need to look at is "Types". Types dictate what type of info is stored in a variable. A simple example is if you type `x = "word" + 3`. You are trying to add a string type and an integer type together, which you can't do because they are different types. In your example you are trying to use `loads()` on an item that's not a JSON document when it expects one. You might want to read up on some [basic type concepts](https://www.activestate.com/blog/introduction-to-python-data-types/) and how they work. Sorry, wall of text.

Comment: @Lagis Good to hear mate! And welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't forget to mark the question as answered.